# Reassigning global variables in a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global-variables

I have simplified the code I have on the site to something more manageable, but the basis of what I'm trying to do is there.

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var d = 0;
var total = a + b + c + d

$('.button').click(function(){
    a = 20;
});
$('button2').click(function(){
    b = 40;
});

$('.totaldiv').html("Your total is " + total)
```

So the goal is for the total to be displayed at 0. Then if you click the button, the total increases to 20. But if you only hit button 2, total would be 40. But if you hit both, it would display as 60.

The issue Im having is that no matter how I seem to arrange it, it just continuously displays the total in totaldiv as 0. Should I be performing the total calculation in each button's function? I have also tried defining the variables in the function using "window.b = 40" to make them apply to the global variables.

Comment: Are you never updating the HTML in `.totaldiv` - that piece of code is only going to run once, at the start.

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is, instead, how it is supposed to know that it should update the total, you're not telling it anywhere else that total should be updated and print inside your div `totaldiv`. The problem is not global-variables related, but rather event-related, there is a piece of logic missing in your code. (also, button2 is neither a class nor an element, was it supposed to be .button2?)

Comment: Yes, the button2 is a class in my actual code, but I did learn that my function that was supposed to be updating the totaldiv was not running properly, so in a roundabout way, you guys helped me out by getting me to troubleshoot it. Thanks!